# Android Bluetooth crash when device is not connected

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm having a serial Bluetooth device connected to my android app. It works well, but only when the device is on..

When my bluetooth device ("Gps_3.3v_4800") device is off my app crashes when it starts. Is there a way to see if its on? Or anyway to prevent my app from crashing.

```
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                btDevice[i] = device.getName();
                System.out.println(device.getName() + device.getAddress() + " \n");

                // Connect to my device
                if(device.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Gps_3.3v_4800")) {
                        Thread ct = new ConnectThread(device, mBluetoothAdapter);
                        isct = new ConnectedThread(((ConnectThread) ct).getSocket());
                        ((ConnectedThread)isct).setJavascript(javascr);
                        ((ConnectedThread)isct).write("hallo");
                        isct.start();
                }
}
```

**My error when device is not on:**

*Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 3928 (Thread-4174)*

**Update**
Now I'm getting a null pointer 
(java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellobt/com.example.hellobt.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException)
Trying to stop the thread when it wont connect..

Comment: What exception does it throw? surround it in a try/catch block and handle the exception properly

Comment: did you used Bluetooth permission:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

Comment: Yes I did, also BLUETOOTH_ADMIN. I think thats not the problem, because it can connect with the device.

Comment: can you show us the line that causes the exception?

Comment: You need to post the full stack dump of the error, and the code which is on whatever line numbers (corresponding to code you wrote) that are mentioned in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with checking:

**if(mmSocket.isConnected())**

I think there is only a problem when a phone is connected with another device. But for me that is ok.

Thank you all.